# post-commit hook run as what user in svn

Tags: svn, post-commit

Apache on a windows machine running as SYSTEM.
What user and password should be used for a post-commit.bat?

I am trying to copy content to a directory for testing on a developer version on the webserver and don't seem to have it working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hook scripts will be launched by the server, so you only need to make sure the corresponding user (SYSTEM for you) has

- read/write access to the repositories (which should already be the case)
- read/execute access to the hook script

Depending on what your script does, you may need more, for example if it creates a log - if it accesses other resources in general. That's probably the problem you have encountered.

Also, if the hook script is a .bat, the `COMSPEC` environment variable is needed to find the shell (I had this problem with Windows XP, it was mainly due to a bad configuration). This variable is typically defined as `C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe`. `PATH` is also very important of course.

Note that it could be misleading, when you test the script with another user login you may have another access your server identity won't.

---

**Edit:** It is possible to set or expand important environment variables like `PATH` and `COMSPEC` at the beginning of the batch script, if you are not sure what they contain with the server account. For example,

```
SET ComSpec=%SystemRoot%\system32\cmd.exe
SET PATH=%PATH%;C:\Tools\SVN\svn-win32-1.4.6\bin
```

Sometimes it is easier than being in the dark and trying to modify the server's account.

Comment: I didn't resolve my issue of my post-commit.bat running , but these user, and path suggestions were helpful in eliminating those potential issues. Thanks

Comment: Debugging those hook scripts is very difficult sometimes as it's hard to be in the same conditions to test it. If you still have this problem, you could 1) produce a log file at the very beginning of the script (careful about the permissions!) and further in the script to trace it; 2) open a command shell window under the same account as the server and launch it manually with plausible parameters. In the log file, you could also dump all the env. variables (set > log.txt), that's often the problem.